# need database hourly data before two months

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, group-by

I have a table with cpuload,freememory,diskspace, cpu utilization and hostname feilds. i am running a cron job to get the data for every 10 mins in all hosts(ex: 4 hosts). 
Now i have one year data in database.

i want to convert that data into hourly average data. but i need only for the data which is before two months. last two months data should not disturb.
my data is like this

```
 hostname              | cpuload | freedisk  | freemem |timestamp 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.15    | 136052    | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:10:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.03    | 136492    | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:20:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.01    | 133456    | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:30:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.10    | 64544     | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:40:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.01    | 68148     | 383660  | 2017-08-01 01:00:08
```

every 10 mins data will add till today i.e `2017-10-12 11:00:00`

now i want to take two months ago data i.e from 2017-08-12 11:00:00 to 2017-08-01 00:00:00 data i need to convert to hourly data

```
SELECT Avg(CpuLoad) AS avgcpuload
    ,Avg(FreeMemory) AS avgfreemem
    ,Avg(FreeDisk) AS avgfreedisk
    ,Avg(Cpu_util) AS avgcpuutil
FROM Dynamic_Host_Information;
```

i got `avg` but i want it for two months back data only.

please help me in this. 
thanks in advance
sagar reddy

Comment: Do you want to retrieve previous 2 months data as it and before that just `avg`? kindly share some sample data and desired output.

Comment: first i want to get 2 months before data and avg 10 mins data to hourly average (2 months before data ,not previous 2 months data).

Comment: Previous 2 months data. i got it. but `avg 10 mins data to hourly average` i don't get this phrase. Can you kindly share sample data and desired output to help us help you.

Comment: i updated my post according to ur suggestion

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to `group by` your data by `date and hour only` part of your `timestamp` column along with a `where` clause to exclude previous `2` months data as below to get your desired result.

```
SELECT t1.hostname
    ,avg(cpuload) AS cpuload
    ,avg(freedisk) AS freedisk
    ,avg(freemem) AS freemem
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP < current_timestamp - interval '42' day
GROUP BY date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H');
```

`INTERVAL '42' DAY` is used to exclude `Oct` and `Sep` data. You can adjust it accordingly.

**Result:**

```
hostname                cpuload     freedisk      freemem
-------------------------------------------------------------
localhost.localdomain   0.072500    117636.0000   383660.0000
localhost.localdomain   0.010000    68148.0000    383660.0000
```

---

**Update 1:**

If you need data for the time period mentioned in question.

```
SELECT t1.hostname
    ,avg(cpuload) AS cpuload
    ,avg(freedisk) AS freedisk
    ,avg(freemem) AS freemem
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP between '2017-08-01 00:00:00' and '2017-08-12 11:00:00'
GROUP BY date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H');
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/OPUZX7960)**

Comment: Thank you zarruq. i need some more help on the same. sorry for asking without trying. i am new to this database. Here i want to insert the results to same table and delete the 2 months ago data where we did the operation. Can u help me

Comment: Kindly ask another question by referring the current question . we will be delighted to help you. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much zarruq :)

Comment: please help me to update obtained results into same table and delete old data from table