# how to delete and update the rows when converetd mins data to hours in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, group-by

this is continuation of the post 
[need database hourly data before two months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701403/need-database-hourly-data-before-two-months)

```
hostname              | cpuload | freedisk  | freemem |timestamp 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.15    | 136052    | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:10:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.03    | 136492    | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:20:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.01    | 133456    | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:30:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.10    | 64544     | 383660  | 2017-08-01 00:40:08 
 localhost.localdomain | 0.01    | 68148     | 383660  | 2017-08-01 01:00:08
```

output obtained is

```
hostname                cpuload     freedisk      freemem
-------------------------------------------------------------
localhost.localdomain   0.072500    117636.0000   383660.0000
localhost.localdomain   0.010000    68148.0000    383660.0000
```

i used query

```
SELECT t1.hostname
    ,avg(cpuload) AS cpuload
    ,avg(freedisk) AS freedisk
    ,avg(freemem) AS freemem
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP < current_timestamp - interval '42' day
GROUP BY date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H');
```

Here i want to insert the results obtained to same table and delete the 2 months ago data where we did the operation.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

sagar reddy

Comment: if you want insert and the delete  ..   is not clear so you cancel the data inserted  .. explain better you need  please

Comment: here my concern is i am inserting data for every 10 mins. per hour 4 records. per day 96. for two moths 96 * 60 . so that i want to convert to hours average. so converted into hours. now obtained data need to be updated in same table and mins data need to be deleted.

Comment: @sagarreddy: Do the newly inserted rows has `null` values in column `timestamp`.

Comment: no they will be having the timestamp value. i am using shell script to do this. if it is possible using shell also fine. i am trying from shell too

Answer (score 0):

You can insert newly generated data using `insert-select` as below.

```
insert into table1 
SELECT t1.hostname
    ,avg(cpuload) AS cpuload
    ,avg(freedisk) AS freedisk
    ,avg(freemem) AS freemem,
    date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%d %H')as timestamp
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP < current_timestamp - interval '42' day
GROUP BY date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H');
```

After the insertion, the table will look like below.

```
hostname                cpuload    freedisk    freemem  timestamp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
localhost.localdomain   0.15       136052      383660   01.08.2017 00:10:08
localhost.localdomain   0.03       136492      383660   01.08.2017 00:20:08
localhost.localdomain   0.01       133456      383660   01.08.2017 00:30:08
localhost.localdomain   0.10       64544       383660   01.08.2017 00:40:08
localhost.localdomain   0.01       68148       383660   01.08.2017 01:00:08
localhost.localdomain   0.07       117636      383660   01.08.2017 00:00:00
localhost.localdomain   0.01       68148       383660   01.08.2017 01:00:00
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DLEW11093)**

You can then delete old data using below query.

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE TIMESTAMP NOT IN (
        SELECT TIMESTAMP
        FROM (
            SELECT date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS TIMESTAMP
            FROM table1 t1
            WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP < current_timestamp - interval '42' day
            GROUP BY date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H')
            ) x
        );
```

Kindly note that as your table don't have an insertion `timestamp` column or any other using which rows can be identified, the above query is written on the assumption that your table do not contain the exact timestamp of the new generated rows.

---

**Update 1:**

If you want to delete data for a specific time period, you can mention it in where clause as below.

```
DELETE
FROM table1
WHERE TIMESTAMP NOT IN (
        SELECT TIMESTAMP
        FROM (
            SELECT date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS TIMESTAMP
            FROM table1 t1
            WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP < current_timestamp - interval '42' day
            GROUP BY date_format(t1.TIMESTAMP, '%Y%m%d%H')
            ) x
        )
    AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2017-08-01 00:00:00'
        AND '2017-09-30 11:00:00';
```

Hope this will give you an idea :-)

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/AYNONI16478)**

Comment: if this data is there in table insert into table1 values('localhost.localdomain',0.01,68148 ,383660,'2017-10-12 01:00:08'); it should not delete last two months data . thanks . i will check it

Comment: this row will be deleted. Only the rows having the exact `timestamp` value of newly inserted rows will not be deleted. You can also restrict deletion to a certain time period by introducing a `where` clause like the `select` statement